# Using While loop inside async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, async-await

I'm trying to use a while loop inside an async function, and I suspect my `resolve();` is messing up the loop, but I'm not sure what to do about it. Here's the code I have:

```js
app.get("/meal-plan", async function(req, res) {
    var calorieCount = req.query.calorieCount;
    var mealInput = parseInt(req.query.mealInput);
    var dietInput = req.query.food;
    var goalPerMeal = (calorieCount / mealInput);
    var whichDiet = "diet." + dietInput;

    var breakfastGoal = goalPerMeal;

    var breakfastArr = [];

    async function getBreakfastArr() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var breakfastQuery = {"breakfast": true, [whichDiet]: true};

            while (breakfastGoal >= 150) {
                Food.count(breakfastQuery, function(err, count) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);

                        Food.findOne(breakfastQuery).skip(random).exec(
                            function(err, result) {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                } else {
                                    breakfastGoal -= result.nutrition.calories;
                                    breakfastArr.push(result);
                                    resolve();
                                }
                             });
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    }

    try {
        await getBreakfastArr();
        console.log(breakfastArr);

        res.render("meal-plan.ejs", { meal: mealInput, calories: calorieCount, diet: dietInput, breakfast: breakfast, lunch: lunch, dinner: dinner, totalCalories: totalCalories});

    } catch (e) {
        res.json(e);
    }
});
```

The `goalPerMeal` variable takes a user calorie input and divides it by the number of meals they select on my form. I then set that value to a specific breakfast variable called `breakfastGoal`. The async function finds a random recipe from my database and adds it to my array, `breakfastArr`. Once it finds the recipe, it subtracts that recipe's calorie count from the `breakfastGoal`.

I want this function to run until `breakfastGoa`l is reduced to below 150; however, it doesn't seem to work. If I remove the while loop, the function will successfully find the breakfast item, add it to the array, and subtract its calorie count from `breakfastGoal`. The only thing breaking it is adding the while loop.

Is this something to do with the `resolve();` in the async function, or am I missing something important?

Any help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: What response do you get then ? nothing ? undefined ?

Comment: @raphaelSeguin Apologies for not adding this. When I try to load the page that triggers my app.get, I get infinite loading (i.e. the page never loads). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Do you think something like this will work? I have not tested this. Just an idea. 
put the while block inside the else block and call recursively.

```
async function getBreakfastArr() {
  let breakfastQuery = { "breakfast": true, [whichDiet]: true };
  return this.getRandomRecipe(breakfastQuery).then((response)=>{
        return response; //the response will have your breakfast goal
  });
}


async function getRandomRecipe(breakfastQuery) {

   return Food.count(breakfastQuery, function (err, count) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
      Food.findOne(breakfastQuery).skip(random).exec(
        function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            breakfastGoal -= result.nutrition.calories;
            breakfastArr.push(result);
            while (breakfastGoal >= 150) {
               this.getRandomRecipe(breakfastQuery);
            }
            return Promise.resolve(breakfastGoal);
          }
        });
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I get a warning on the getRandomRecipe resolve() (I guess it's trying to find a Promise). When I add "return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { })" around the code, it breaks. Any ideas?

Comment: I made some modifications. can you try that and let me know the error you get. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you create only one promise, but have several asynchronous results you need to wait for in the `while` loop.

The first time `resolve` is called, that sole promise is resolved, and that will make the code following the `await` to execute. But at that time your array is not finished at all. Also, any further calls to `resolve` will not influence that promise any more: a promise can only be resolved once. The other calls are ignored.

The solution is to make a promise in each iteration of the `while` loop, and `await` it.

Change this:

```
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var breakfastQuery = {"breakfast": true, [whichDiet]: true};
        while (breakfastGoal >= 150) {
```

to this:

```
    var breakfastQuery = {"breakfast": true, [whichDiet]: true};
    while (breakfastGoal >= 150) {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```

The code could be improved more, but it is not relevant to your question. For instance, it would be better to make each promise resolve with the value to be added to the array `breakfastArr`, so that you would have:

```
        breakfastArr.push(await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             // ...
                           resolve(result)
             // ...
        });
```

And the `async` function should *return* that array, so that it does not have to be defined at the top.

Comment: When I try this, my IDE gives me an error "Parsing error: unexpected token new" on the await new Promise. Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind -- I'm an idiot and forgot to remove the return new Promise. This worked. Thanks very much man -- spent hours on this today. And thank you for the tips on improvement.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are mixing callback taking functions with promises. The proper way to do this is to wrap only the callback taking functions in promise constructors. The result is some thing like this:

```
app.get("/meal-plan", async function(req, res) {

  var calorieCount = req.query.calorieCount;
  var mealInput = parseInt(req.query.mealInput);
  var dietInput = req.query.food;
  var goalPerMeal = (calorieCount / mealInput);
  var whichDiet = "diet." + dietInput;

  var breakfastGoal = goalPerMeal;

  function count(query) {
    Food.count(query, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        reject(error)
      } else {
        resolve(result)
      }
    });
  }

  function findOne(query, count) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Food.findOne(query).skip(count).exec(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          reject(error)
        } else {
          resolve(result)
        }
      });
    });
  }

  async function getBreakfastArr() {
    let breakfastQuery = {
      "breakfast": true,
      [whichDiet]: true
    };
    let breakfastArr = [];
    while (breakfastGoal >= 150) {
      let count = await count(breakfastQuery);
      let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
      let result = await findOne(breakfastQuery, random);
      breakfastGoal -= result.nutrition.calories;
      breakfastArr.push(result);
    }
    return breakfastArr
  }

  try {
    let breakfastArr = await getBreakfastArr();
    console.log(breakfastArr);

    res.render("meal-plan.ejs", {
      meal: mealInput,
      calories: calorieCount,
      diet: dietInput,
      breakfast: breakfast,
      lunch: lunch,
      dinner: dinner,
      totalCalories: totalCalories
    });

  } catch (e) {
    res.json(e);
  }

});
```

Some of the Promise libraries had a function called promisify that would take a function taking a callback as its last argument which took node style (err, result) arguments and produced a function that when called returned a promise. If that is available the wrappers get a lot smaller. for example the `Food.count` wrapper becomes `let count = promisify(Food.count);` or`let count = promisify(Food.count.bind(Food));`

Comment: Mongo methods already return promises. This can be greatly simplified as a result to avoid explicit promise contructor anti-pattern

Comment: @charlietfl I wasn't sure what returned a promise. I don't use Mongo enough to know. But I was attempting to at least show that the Promise constructor should not appear except as a wrapper around functions that take callbacks. If the functions  return a Promise when not given a callback that would remove the need to wrap.

Comment: Right...I don't use it a lot either but know they have versions that return promise when callback not provided and that removes need for external promisify

Answer (score -3):

You are returning a promise from async function which is not required. You can remove async from the function returning promise.
So I suggest removing async from function getBreakfastArr()

Comment: This isn't an answer and should be deleted.  It is nothing more than a comment and that is what comment blocks are for